# vim you complete me error on c++11 syntax

Tags: c++, vim, c++11, clang, vim-plugin

I installed `You Complete Me` with `Vundle` and then ran

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

And added

```
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleMe/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
```

to my `vimrc` file.

Now when I write `C++11` code, `ycm` gives me syntax errors!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What C++ code, and which exact error do you get?!

Comment: for example `for(auto& v : vec)` gives me error . `auto type specifier is not complatibe with c++98`

Comment: You should not use the default `.ycm_extra_conf.py` without modifiyng it. It's more like a template then a ready-to-use file.

Comment: the default file is fine for me , and it does the job .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

commenting `-Wc++98-compat` flag in `~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleMe/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py` did the job for me .

Comment: I did the same, but it shows the `'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension` warning...

Comment: Haha, sorry for misleading, I forgot I was loading a local config.

Comment: I think the path is now
`~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py`